# M:N relation in sql table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to figure out the best way to setup some tables in my database.
I will be saving data about users in one table and navigations in another.
I will simplify the tables.

I have two tables at the moment, 
User that has User_ID and User_Name.
Navigation that has Nav_ID and Nav_Name.

What i'm thinking about is that Every user can have there "own" navigation counter.
So basicly what i'm trying to do is that the Nav_ID counter will start on 1 for every user.

The way it works now is that every user uses the same navigation table and the Nav_ID counts from 1 for everyone.

I'm thinking that i need to make a 1:n to n:1 table in the middle to connect the User and Navigation tables together. Or is there another way, heard something about surrogates or something but i dont know if its a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a one-to-one relationship where each user has one navigation record, or a one to many relationship, where each user has multiple navigation records (but each navigation record only links to one user):

Your Navigation table might look like this:

```
Nav_id, User_ID, Counter
```

I don't think there's any need for a third table.

Navigation.User_ID is a foreign key to User.User_ID.

```
User
User_ID   Name
      1   Marcus
      2   David

Navigation
Nav_ID     User_ID     Count
     1           1         1
     2           2         1
```

Though, for a one to one relationship, if navigation is just one field, you could even just store it as a field in User:

```
User
User_ID    Name     Navigation_Count
      1    Marcus                  1
      2    David                   2
```

You'll only need a third table if there is a many to many relationship, where you have users and navigation records, but each user may link to multiple navigation records, and users may share the same navigation records.

Answer (score 0):

If nav_id starts at 1 for every user and each users navigation records are related to that user you have a weak table.  The relation will be 1:N from users to navigation.  The primary key for navigation will be the compound key: user_id, nav_id. You will likely have to build custom code to increment the nav_id for each user.

You could have a single column surrogate key on navigation which auto-increments across all users.  This would be the primary key on the navigations table.  However, I don't think this would be useful.  You will still need to implement the natural primary key as unique constraint.